# Using Perl's DBIx::Connector module on FastCGI web page

Tags: multithreading, perl, cgi, fastcgi, dbix-class

Anyone has experience using the [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) module for [FastCGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Fast) pages? I googled around for a Perl implementation of DB Connection Pooling and found this `DBIx::Connector` module on CPAN which seems like it can be used for such functionality on FastCGI web pages. If you already had some experience using it, could you help clarifying some questions based on a sample script below? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

1. The global scoped `$conn` object is thread-safe and shared among all http's GET request threads inside the while loop ?
2. In each individual http's GET request thread, the `$conn->dbh()` method will either:
   a. Return/Re-use an existing `$dbh` obj. if it already exists. OR:
   b. Instantiate and return a brand new `$dbh` obj. if there's no existing ones?
3. In the case the DB server goes down and then goes back up, which causes `$conn` to disconnect, how do we re-establish/re-activate this global `$conn` object ? ( from what I understand about FastCGI, all global vars. above the while loop only get declared once on web-server startup, and only those inside the while loop are declared for every http GET request.. )

Example code:

```
use CGI::Fast;
use DBIx::Connector;

# Global var. for all http GET request threads
my $conn = DBIx::Connector->new( $dsn, $username, $password, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 1,
});

# Handling individual http GET request thread
while ( $q = CGI::Fast->new ) {
  my $dbh    = $conn->dbh ;

  my $cursor1 = $dbh->prepare( sqlString1 ) ;
  $cursor1->execute() ;
 
  my $cursor2 = $dbh->prepare( sqlString2 ) ;
  $cursor2->execute() ;

  ...
} #end individual http GET request thread
```

Comment: I am not familiar with FastCGI, but from reading the documentation for [CGI::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Fast) and [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector), the answer to question 1. would be yes, but the easiest way to determine is to test it for yourself. By looking at [the source](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Connector/source/lib/DBIx/Connector.pm) for `DBIx::Connector` the answer to question 2. would be yes. For question 3, it seems like you do not need to reestablish `$conn` since `$conn->dbh` will reconnect if the connection is missing?

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland! I'll do some more testings...