# How to pass perl $dbh objects between scripts

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I have to maintain some Perl CGI scripts in our production codebase. The problem is that when the CGI job runs, it takes some time to instantiate the Perl DB's $dbh object before it could be used to run various SQLs, retrieve data and do some stuff. I'm thinking about setting up a separate Perl demon script constantly running in a loop, saving bunch of $dbh objects into a Queue. So that the original CGI script can just pop a $dbh off the demon script's Queue, run its SQLs, and return the $dbh back to the queue once done. Problem is i don't know the mechanism to implement the communication between the CGI script and the dbhGenerator demon script?? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Example process flow:
dbhGenerator script: run in a while loop, adding $dbh objects into a Queue

CGI-script: communicates with dbhGenerator to pop off 1 $dbh from its Queue to run various SQLs; then return the $dbh back to dbhGenerator's queue once done.

EDIT 1:
If and when fork/thread need to be involved, which one is better to use: Parallel::ForkManager or "use threads;"? we use Perl version 5.36.

Comment: I was wondering about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059147/using-perls-dbixconnector-module-on-fastcgi-web-page

Comment: Avoid the CGI entirely and go to a FastCGI daemon. The available web frameworks should all support FastCGI.

Comment: Thanks @Ian/@ikegami. I rememeber someone mention that the Perl $dbh handle object does not work with multi threads. So even if I go with the FastCGI approach, I still need to store separate $dbh objects into a Pool queue and let various threads do a pop() to do its SQLs tasks and then return the $dbh back to the pool once done. Is that correct?

Comment: _forking vs threads_  -- Can't tell just so; it depends on what and how need be done.  In the coarsest sense they're somewhat similar in Perl since threads in Perl aren't nimble and cheap things that one might expect by the name; they are best used for longer jobs.  Threads are in principle a more advanced topic than forking. On the other hand, they come with a nice API and a good queue lib. (But communication slows things down.)  Best play a little with both to get a feel for it.  Various other frameworks come with support for asynchronous work.

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea. The thing is, the script running the database queries needs a database  connection, what `$dbh` embodies. I'm not sure that one can make it work by passing (serializing and re-constructing) such an object from *another program*?

What surely can be done is to make it into a little client-server system -- Have your "daemon-script" also execute queries that are passed to it, collect results as suitable, and return that.
Then the CGI-script forms an SQL string and passes it to the server and takes the retured results.

The communication could go over a socket, for example.

Comment: Thanks @zdim, feel free to address my question in the commend section above. Thanks.

Comment: @santa100  For comment about "_multi threads_" -- as stated in this answer, I don't see how passing an object to another program can work, and that applies to threaded programs as well.  If you want -- if you _need_ -- concurrent processing then you can make the program with database connection(s) fork or spawn threads.  So when it receives a request (SQL string) it can fork a process or use a thread (prepared beforehand) and run the SQL. But that complicates code _a lot_, probably for not much speed benefit altogether.  Just how complex are those DB operations?

Comment: right now the CGI script still operates at an acceptable rate. We're trying to look for way to reduce the totale runtime since the starting up of a $dbh handle object ( we timed the before-after of the $dbh = DBI->connect() statement ) takes up roughly 1/3 the total runtime, hence the inquiry to see if it's possible not having to start, close, and restart a $dbh every single time.

Comment: @santa100 The idea from your question is good I think, but modified as in this answer: that the other script manages all database work -- has live connection(s) _and_ runs SQL as passed to it, then returns the result.  Then your CGI is freed to build SQL and process the results.  (I am not sure why/whether threads would get involved...)

Comment: @santa100 If the DB queries may take longer the "server" (the other script which has connections and runs queries) _can_ fork/thread each query but that will complicate the code considerably.

Comment: thanks @zdim. I've edited the OP to add a question about whether to use fork or thread?

Comment: @santa100 By your description, in the context of this answer both threads and forks seem to fit, as the CGI script sends a job (SQL string) to the "server."  The server can put it on the thread queue etc. Then you may need to manage the pool.  Or the server could fork a process for each new job instead; then you'd need to do some form of IPC for it (what isn't hard). If you are thinking about processing the results returned to the CGI script, then pretty much the same story goes. Also see my comment under the Q.